# Why is this .fit method showing the value error?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, object-detection

I was doing my project on YOLO v3, making few changes by changing all 3x3 kernel convolutions to depth wise convolutions, and I was stuck at this error.

Here is my [colaboratory](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1M8VJuifWPc5aeBSJ3YefOQ8teXMx0c0K?usp=sharing) if anyone wanna see the code.

`trained_model.compile(tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(), metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.FalseNegatives(), tf.keras.metrics.FalsePositives(), tf.keras.metrics.TruePositives()] ) trained_model.fit( x=X_train,y=y_train, epochs =10 , batch_size =10 )`

[Value error: Shapes (10, 1024, 1024, 3, 85) and (10, 3) are incompatible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/53eP4.png)

Comment: We do not take code as colab links, include the actual and relevant code in the question itself.

Comment: I am new to stack overflow, how can I add my complete code, it's approximately around 40 to 50 cells. Help me doing it.